# How do I clean up file permissions for a directory structure

Tags: linux, file-permissions

Here's the situation: I have two copies of a directory structure where the files may have different contents, but the names and locations are the same.  And one of the structures has correct file permissions (i.e. the executable files are marked as executable, the non-executable ones aren't), and I need to copy those permissions to the other tree.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Given *source* (complete path to start of the directory with the correct permissions) and *target* (complete path to start of the directory that needs its permissions changed)

```
chmod -R a-x target
find target -type d -exec chmod a+x {} \;
chmod a+x `find source -executable -type f | grep -v "Permission denied" | sed 's/source/target/'`
```

1. Mark everything as being not executable
2. Mark all directories as being executable
3. Find every file in *source* that is executable, and mark its matching file in *target* as being executable, stripping out the ones where there's a problem.

Comment: If your directory structure is large, you might want to use xargs in the last line instead of the backquotes (to avoid command line parameter count limit).

Comment: This seems fine, but note that it's going to fail in pathological cases where for example a directory has executable access but not read access, etc...  It also fails to handle other kinds of permissions bits like setuid/setgit and the sticky bit.  And of course it also ignores non-Unix metadata like ext2 attributes containing selinux labels, etc...  A general solution here is going to be pretty hairy.

Comment: Your handling of "Permission denied" is wrong - you grepping `stdout` while this message will be outputed to `stderr`